# SVG path and de Casteljau's algorithm give different results WPF

Tags: wpf, algorithm, graphics, graph-algorithm, bezier

I make implementation of de Casteljau's algorithm that draw on WPF and it's look's good with Tangent point (red rectangle)

[image]

but I found that it's give different result with this case

> M 149,256 C 149,198 195,149 256,150 326,150 370,196 370,256 371,317
> 328,366 256,366 190,365 147,313 149,256 Z

[image]
[image]

so is there something I miss?

```
public List<MyLines> Calc2(double t, List<MyLines> lines_ = null)
        {
            bool first = false;

            if (lines_ == null)
            {
                lines_ = lines;
                first = true;
            }

            if (lines.Count == 0)
                return lines;
            else if (lines_.Count == 1)
            {
                var tmp = new MyLines();
                tmp.x1 = tmp.x2 = (1 - t) * lines_[0].x1 + t * lines_[0].x2;
                tmp.y1 = tmp.y2 = (1 - t) * lines_[0].y1 + t * lines_[0].y2;
                TangentPoint = new MyPoint() { x = tmp.x2, y = tmp.y2 };
                return new List<MyLines>() { tmp };
            }

            List<MyLines> Res_lines = new List<MyLines>();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines_.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                double X1 = (1 - t) * lines_[i].x1 + t * lines_[i].x2;
                double Y1 = (1 - t) * lines_[i].y1 + t * lines_[i].y2;

                double X2 = (1 - t) * lines_[i + 1].x1 + t * lines_[i + 1].x2;
                double Y2 = (1 - t) * lines_[i + 1].y1 + t * lines_[i + 1].y2;

                Res_lines.Add(new MyLines() { x1 = X1, x2 = X2, y1 = Y1, y2 = Y2 ,id=id_++});
            }

            if (Res_lines.Count == 1)
                TangentLine = Res_lines[0];
            
            Res_lines.AddRange(Calc2(t, Res_lines));
            return Res_lines;
        }
```

Comment: It looks as if you applied de Casteljau's algorithm on all 12 line segments, but you should apply it to the four arcs that represent a quarter-circle separately. Bézier curves are defined piecewise and the pooints have different meanings: Every third point is a point on the curve, the intermediate point are "auxiliary" points that define the tangents, but are usually not on the curve. (SVG paths allow you to leave out redundant C commands, but your curve is made up of four C's, the last three hidden.)

Comment: @MOehm thank you you save me